# How to Run PHP application on a port rather than in htdocs folder?

Tags: php, node.js, server, xampp, backend

When we run a nodejs app, it gets bound to a port on the machine from where we can access it.
Is there any similar way to run a PHP app rather than just going to default location which is through xampp htdocs folder?

I would like to avoid storing my files in htdocs folder.

Comment: The port a server listens on has nothing at all to do with directories/folders.  Both answers you received explain this in detail.

Answer (score 3):

You're conflating a couple different issues.

PHP is traditionally executed via CGI or or a FastCGI (PHP-FPM) daemon.  In these cases, the web server itself (such as Nginx or Apache) is what listens on a port, and it communicates to PHP via these protocols.  Most Node.js applications serving HTTP requests skip the CGI and FastCGI route and run an HTTP daemon themselves.  It's common to still have a proper web server in front, to handle buffering for slow clients and caching.

The way to think about this is that for *most* (certainly not all) Node.js applications, HTTP is used instead of FastCGI.  (And, as a bonus, if you want to just have clients connect directly to Node.js, you can, skipping the need for the web server entirely.)

Now, on to application directory structure...  It is best practice to actually leave your application code *outside of your document root*.  One real easy way to do this is have a single file, such as an `index.php`, that receives all routes (configured via rewrite rules in your web server), which then loads and executes the appropriate code.  On disk, the rest of this application code lives outside of the document root, and can be loaded via simple `require()`/`include()`.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.4.0 you can start your own server with [PHP Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

> As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server.
>
> The web server **runs a only one single-threaded process**, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

**Example for:**
- **runs a only one single-threaded process** - means if you try to **cURL** or **file_get_contents**, or do any request on the same domain you'll end up in a loop and stuck the server, because PHP is sync and this one is single-threaded.

**Example provided from docs**

**router.php**

```
<?php
// router.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
} else { 
    echo "<p>Welcome to PHP</p>";
}
?>
```

Then in your terminal type `php -S localhost:8000 router.php` to start the server.

> I would like to avoid storing my files in htdocs folder.

To specify another document root add the `-t` argument:

`php -S localhost:8000 -t /path/to/project router.php`

I wrote a while ago a nodejs package [node-php-awesome-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php-awesome-server) that aims to do just that, you can start a nodejs webserver that renders php, set php environment variables, alter ini settings ... still using this today bundled with webpack middleware for server-side rendering.

If you're interested only in php for now, try their build in server, if that default router doesn't cover what you need, i have written a router to tackle several frameworks [PHP-Built-in-web-server-Router](https://github.com/darklightcode/PHP-Built-in-web-server-Router)

Comment: Is this support .htaccess

Comment: No, php doesn't know .htaccess, only apache knows that. But you can create your custom routes/conditions for the router to interpret, just make use of the $_SERVER variable.